# How can we set a Button is By default selected in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, magento2.2.7

I need help, there are three buttons in my phtml file , In that page I want to one button is selected by default when the page is load or refresh in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#modal").click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the script in your phtml file,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
      'jquery'
    ], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#buttonId").trigger('click');
        });
    })'
</script>
```